# Tie a marker to the center of a circle

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have an editable circle on my map and I wanted to see if it's possible to have a marker always appear at the center of the circle. I know I can have a marker and move it to the center of the circle whenever it's moved. The problem is that circles do not have a "while being dragged" event so I should wait for the dragging to stop and then move the marker to the new center.

Comment: Can you have an event listener for the `center_changed` event on the circle object?

Comment: You want to [bind](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject) the center of the circle to the position of a marker?

Comment: @duncan: yes, but as I said, I want the marker to move while the circle is being moved, not just when it's done moving.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes, I looked at the link you gave me but I cannot understand how to apply it to my case
bindTo(key:string, target:MVCObject, targetKey?:string, noNotify?:boolean)

Comment: What does the rest of your (relevant) code look like?  Can you provide a jsfiddle that shows your existing functionality?

Comment: I figured it out. I use:
marker.bindTo('position', circle, 'center' ); 
where marker is my marker object and circle the circle object. However, the browser (chrome) crashes when I move one. strange.

Comment: Oh, and the error was because I had event handlers to move one when the other does. After removing those and just letting the bindTo take care of things, it works OK. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now, when I move the marker, the circle moves along with it. But when I move the circle, the marker stays put and only moves to the center of the circle when I'm done moving the circle. I think that's because circle's do not have a 'drag' event.

Comment: It works for me if I make the circle in [this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/articles/mvcfun/step4) draggable.  From [this "article" in the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/articles/mvcfun)

Comment: You're right. It should be draggable to trigger the drag event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bind](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject) the center of the circle to the position of a marker

See [this "article" in the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/articles/mvcfun)

[Proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_mvcfun_step4_draggable.html)

Relevant changed code from that example:

```
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeWeight: 2,
      draggable: true
    });
```